# Grails CRUD list order by a field

Tags: grails

I have a domain class Project as below

```
class Project {
    String projectName
    String projectCode
    String techLead
    String projectManager
    Date deliveryDate
    String currentPhase
    Integer priority

}
```

I have controller as below

```
class ProjectController {
def scaffold = Project

def index = {
redirect(action:list,params:params)
}

def list = {
// displays only 10 records per page
if (!params.max) params.max = 10
[ projectList: Project.list( params ) ]
}
}
```

I would like to display the list of projects in the sorting order or priority. How can I implement that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `list` action to the below

```
def list = {
  // displays only 10 records per page
  if (!params.max) {
    params.max = 10
  }
  params.sort = "priority" 
  params.order = "asc"  // change to "desc" to sort in the opposite direction

  [projectList: Project.list(params)]      
}
```

Comment: Thanks Donal...Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

A much shorter and more idiomatic way of doing this would be to use the dynamic methods on `list` that provide ordering:

```
def list = {
    [projectList: Project.listOrderByPriority(max: params.max ?: 10)]
}
```

Comment: You could even set this default sort order right in Project domain class like is described in [grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#defaultSortOrder). In some scenarios this solution make sense